# Boundary characterization of harmonic functions on $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

I was reading some paper on Martin/Possion boundaries, but most of them concerned some kind of bounded cases. So I wondered, is there any boundary-like characterization of a kind *there exists an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold $S$ such that any harmonic function on $\Bbb R^n$ can be represented through a function/measure on $S$. Such $S$ is unique up too ...*

Comment: Take a look at *The Royden boundary of a Riemannian manifold* by Glasner and Katz. This may not quite be what you want, but I am not aware of any approaches that represent the harmonic boundary of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a submanifold (or just a subset) in a canonical way.

Comment: @maowao thanks. What is the harmonic boundary exactly?